# Google calendar api: getting eventdetails from different calendars

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

Is it possible with python and the google calendar api to retrieve event details from different calendars.

For example: I want to display a family calendar on one screen. To do this, I want to retrieve all the appointments from the calendars of my wife, my children and me.

I already tried the quickstart.py script from google and added an array with the different calendar ids. But it only retreived event details from one calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this with one request. With [gcsa](https://google-calendar-simple-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can do:

```
from gcsa.google_calendar import GoogleCalendar

gc = GoogleCalendar()
events = list(gc.get_events(start, end, calendar_id='calendar1'))
events.extend(gc.get_events(start, end, calendar_id='calendar2'))
events.extend(gc.get_events(start, end, calendar_id='calendar3'))
...

events.sort() # if you need to sort events by time
```

But you need to have an access to all calendars.

Answer (score 1):

The [events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) method is singular.

> Returns events on the **specified** calendar.

It will only return to you events for the calendar you are questing data for.  Your going to have to do it once for each calendar.